# Fetch and insert product price on a custom page in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to fetch and insert a product price dynamically for a custom page in BigCommerce?

I am creating a custom page detailing specific products in BigCommerce and I would like to be able to fetch the product price for each product from the system instead of manually setting it on the page.

This way if the price is changed for a product the price will of course dynamically change on the custom page.

I know that BigCommerce uses `%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%` to call the price on the product page and in other code throughout the site, but can't figure out how to utilize this on the custom page where I will have multiple products listed.

Comment: Why not create a category for these products, and assign a custom category layout file to get desired layout/functionality?

Comment: @tim-diztinct, that is a great suggestion! Thank you very much. The simplicity of it made it elusive to me.

Answer (score 0):

I really like @tim-diztinct's answer, I would recommend following that if you can.

But otherwise, the alternative/hard way would be to grab the price directly from the live product page using JavaScript.

In BigCommerce, you can quickly get to a product page using one of these two standardized URLs: 
 1. `store_url.com/products.php?product=product name here` 
 2. `store_url.com/products.php?productId=productIdHere` (my preferred)

So then if you wanted to grab the live price from the product page, you could do an Ajax call to the product page, and parse the content for the price...

```js
/**
 * Makes an HTTP GET to an external product page
 * and parses that page for the product's current price.
 * @param pid <int> - The product ID to search for. 
 * @return Promise  - Resolved with product price, reject on fail. 
 */
function getProductPrice(pid) {
  // Ensure pid parameter set:
  if (typeof pid == 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Missing product ID.');
  } else {
    // Ensure pid is a non decimal number:
    pid = parseInt(pid);
  }
  // Return promise to contain the results...
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Make an Ajax GET request to the product page:
    $.get("site_url_here.com/products.php?productId=" +pid, function(res) {
      // If request successful:
      if (res) {
        // The content for the product page is loaded in 'res'. 
        // The Price should be contained within a meta element within a div containing the class name 'Value'.
        // Below, we parse the html response for the meta element containing the price...
        resolve($(res).find('.Value > meta'').attr('content'));
      // Else request failed:
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  });
}

//** Calling the above function **//
getProductPrice(25).then(function(price) {
  // Do something with the price (insert it into your custom page?)
  alert('The product price is ' +price);
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log('Error getting product price - ', e);
});
```

My last piece of advice so you have something to leave with, is that since I imagine you'll have multiple products on your custom page, then you will need to get the prices for each product.

My recommendation is to perhaps include the product ID somewhere related to each product (such as an ID, or a hidden element). Parse all the ID's into an array, so that forEach value you can call the getProductPrice function, and then inject it into the element on your custom page responsible for displaying the price!

Bonus: Save the prices in a cookie that expires every X interval, and read from there for recurring client requests.

/